# Saving user input as a temporary variable in for a discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

This is my first time using discord.py and I was wondering how I could make a variable with the users input after the !command (example user input).

```
@stop.command()
async def episodes(ctx):



    tvshowname  = (userinput) # <---Am trying to get user input here 
    page_url  = "https://whatevermoveiesite.com/" + tvshowname

    #everything else in here is just a web scraper
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the following syntax on your function definition to pass the user input:

```py
@client.command()
async def episodes(ctx, *, user_input=None):
    print(f'User input is {user_input}')
```

Then entering the command `!episodes Spiffy TV Show` (using "!" as prefix) results in:

```
User input is Spiffy TV Show
```